# Fix a problem with surrounding braces in the splitting of an over-long set definition

Tags: math-mode, equations, split, ampersand

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools, unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            |\mu|(B):=\sup\left\{&\sum_{i=1}^k|\mu(B_i)|:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and}\right.\\
            &\left.B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E\text{ are disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kB_i\subseteq B\right\}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

This is how the output looks like:

[image]

I need to break the definition into two lines, since it takes too much horizontal space. Obviously, there is a problem with the braces. Actually, I think I know what's going wrong. The problem is that the first ampersand is occurring after the first `\left\{` but the corresponding closing `\right.` is occurring after the first ampersand. So, I guess that's causing that they cannot match. However, I don't know how I can fix this.

Comment: Please indicate whether you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document.

Comment: @Mico I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. The answer I just posted works equally well (and produces the same output) under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main recommendation is to use `\biggl\{` in the first row and `\biggr\}` in the second. And, since you load the `mathtools` package, I would replace `:=` with `\coloneqq`; this affects how TeX inserts whitespace on either side of ":=".

Optionally, one may encase the `\biguplus_{i=1}^k B_i \subseteq B \biggr\}` code block in a `\smash[t]{...}` wrapper. Doing so allows the two rows of the equation to be spaced a bit more more closely. (`\smash[t]` sets the implicit height of its argument to zero. That's ok here since there's absolutely nothing immediately "above" the `\biguplus_{i=1}^k B_i \subseteq B \biggr\}` material.)

I used LuaLaTeX to compile the following modified version of your code. Using XeLaTeX results in the same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \coloneqq and \DeclarePairedDelimiter macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \abs{\mu}(B) \coloneqq \sup {}\biggl\{
 &\sum_{i=1}^k\abs{\mu(B_i)} :
  \text{$k\in\mathbb{N}$ and}\\
 &\quad\text{$B_1,\dots,B_k\in\mathcal{E}$ 
  are disjoint with }
 \smash[t]{\biguplus_{i=1}^k B_i \subseteq B \biggr\}}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Automatic braces are seldom correct, it is often better to do them manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools, unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            |\mu|(B):=\sup\Bigg\{&\sum_{i=1}^k|\mu(B_i)|:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and}\\
            &B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E\text{ are disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kB_i\subseteq B\Bigg\}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

If you nevertheless want automatic resizing, you can make this little trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools, unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            |\mu|(B):=\sup\left\{\vphantom{\biguplus_{i=1}^k}\right.&\sum_{i=1}^k|\mu(B_i)|:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and} \\
            &\left. B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E\text{ are disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kB_i\subseteq B\right\}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not only the automatic resizing which is going wrong. I also get a compiler error "extra }, or forgotten \right. Missing \right. inserted. Missing \ inserted. Extra \right. Missing { inserted".

Comment: @0xbadf00d this works for me

Answer (score 1):

Your equation I would wrote it on the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, thmtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \[
\abs{\mu(B)}\coloneqq \sup \sum_{i=1}^k\abs{\mu(B_i)},\quad
    \begin{cases}
        k\in\mathbb N\text{ and} \\
        B_1,\dotsc,B_k\in\mathcal{E}\text{ are disjoint with }
            \smash[t]{\biguplus\limits_{i=1}^k B_i \subseteq B}
    \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Some solution in above code are stolen from nice @Mico answer (+1).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,but to be honest, I find the look of your write up pretty ugly and - which is the more important point - I wouldn't be sure what's meant with your equation if I read it somewhere.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, that is your opinion. The same finding I have about your equation :-)

Comment: @Zarko - De gustibus non est disputandum...

Comment: @Mico, I agree with you ...